# How can I play a custom sound in my custom keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, audio, keyboard

I want to play an audio file when a key on my custom keyboard is clicked using swift. I've tried this, however, have had no luck. How can I make this work? Is playing a custom audio sound on a keyboard action possible?

```
func btnPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var btn = sender as UIButton
    var stringToInsert=""
    var proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput

    switch (btn.tag)
    {
    case 10:
        stringToInsert = "a"
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("8bit", ofType: "wav") {
            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), fileTypeHint: "wav", error: nil)

            if let sound = audioPlayer {
                sound.prepareToPlay()
                sound.play()
                println("hello") 
            }
        }
    }
    proxy.insertText(stringToInsert)  
}
}
```

Comment: This code is worked fine for me. But with small change in your code. Just put `if let sound = audioPlayer as AVAudioPlayer?` instead of `if let sound = audioPlayer` and try , may it solves your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks. I still can't get it to work though. The key acts as if its playing the clip, reducing in opacity and staying in the pressed state for several seconds, yet no sound is produced. Perhaps its not possible to play an audio clip from the keyboard?